# css bottom margin not working?

Tags: css

I have the following problem. Somehow, the margin-bottom of *.item* (should be 15px) doesn't work for the last item in *.box*. See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WVP3D/

It might be a basic question, but i've been looking for a solution and couldn't find it. If anyone has the time to help me out, your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working. There's a space between the grey item divs, that's the bottom margin.

You can add bottom padding to the box div if you want the lighter grey below the items. Even just 1px padding works ([FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WVP3D/9/)) Because then, when padding is added to the box div which must occur after the clear div it forces the margin on the item div to be seen by the parent (box).

Comment: Thanks, that appears to do the trick. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: A more correct solution would be to give the parent container a display property (table) that sees the bottom margin of children even without any placeholder padding.

Comment: But the table display property is not supported widely. Adding padding is. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `padding-bottom:15px;` to .item

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table;` to your `.box` class

```
.box {
    ...
    display: table;
    ...
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GnHuJ/1/

Comment: So long as you don't need older IE version support.

Answer (score 0):

Floating the container element (.box) should give you what you want, as can be seen on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf5XQ/)